# socket accepted but m_socket.remote_endpoint raise Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Code:

Listener.hpp:

```
template <typename SocketType>
void Listener<SocketType>::BeginAccept()
{
    auto worker = SelectWorker();
    auto socket = worker->CreateSocket();

    m_acceptor->async_accept(socket->GetAsioSocket(),
        [this, worker, socket] (const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        this->OnAccept(worker, socket, ec);
    });
}

template <typename SocketType>
void Listener<SocketType>::OnAccept(NetworkThread<SocketType> *worker, std::shared_ptr<SocketType> const& socket, const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    // an error has occurred
    if (ec)
        worker->RemoveSocket(socket.get());
    else
        socket->Open();

    BeginAccept();
}
```

Socket.cpp:

```
bool Socket::Open()
{
    try
    {
        const_cast<std::string &>(m_address) = m_socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
        const_cast<std::string &>(m_remoteEndpoint) = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_socket.remote_endpoint());
    }
    catch (boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        sLog.outInfo("Socket::Open() failed to get remote address.  Error: %s", error.message().c_str());
        return false;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& error)
    {
        sLog.outInfo("Socket::Open() failed(with std::exception) to get remote address.  Error: %s", error.what());
        return false;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        sLog.outError("Socket::Open() failed to get remote address.  Other error");
        return false;
    }

    m_outBuffer.reset(new PacketBuffer);
    m_secondaryOutBuffer.reset(new PacketBuffer);
    m_inBuffer.reset(new PacketBuffer);

    StartAsyncRead();

    return true;
}
```

Is this related to TCP attack?

EDIT: gdb:

```
(gdb) p m_socket
$1 = {<boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >> = {<boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, true>> = {
      implementation = {<boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type> = {socket_ = 21, state_ = 80 'P', reactor_data_ = 0x7ffff0005120}, protocol_ = {family_ = 2}}, service_ = 0x7f2b30}, <boost::asio::socket_base> = {
      static message_peek = 2, static message_out_of_band = 1, static message_do_not_route = 4, static message_end_of_record = 128, static max_connections = 128}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) p m_socket.is_open()
$2 = true
(gdb) bt
#0  MaNGOS::Socket::Open (this=0x7ffff0003c40) at /home/ubuntu/MoltenCore/MoltenCore/src/shared/Network/Socket.cpp:52
#1  0x00000000004fbff1 in MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::OnAccept (this=0x7fffffffe6c0, worker=0x8041e0, socket=std::shared_ptr (count 2, weak 1) 0x7ffff0003c40, ec=...) at /home/ubuntu/MoltenCore/MoltenCore/src/shared/Network/Listener.hpp:121
#2  0x00000000004fa030 in MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}::operator()(boost::system::error_code const&) const (__closure=0x7ffff4ec8be0, ec=...)
    at /home/ubuntu/MoltenCore/MoltenCore/src/shared/Network/Listener.hpp:110
#3  0x0000000000502a2d in boost::asio::detail::binder1<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}, boost::system::error_code>::operator()() (this=0x7ffff4ec8be0) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:47
#4  0x00000000005020c3 in boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder1<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}, boost::system::error_code> >(boost::asio::detail::binder1<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}, boost::system::error_code>&, ...) (function=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:69
#5  0x00000000005014b8 in boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder1<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}, boost::system::error_code>, {lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}>(boost::asio::detail::binder1<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}, boost::system::error_code>&, {lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}&) (function=..., context=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:37
#6  0x0000000000500886 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_accept_op<boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::asio::ip::tcp, MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::BeginAccept()::{lambda(boost::system::error_code const&)#1}>::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service*, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) (owner=0x8084d0, base=0x804910) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_accept_op.hpp:123
#7  0x00000000004f0300 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete (this=0x804910, owner=..., ec=..., bytes_transferred=0) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
#8  0x00000000004f1d55 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete (owner=0x8084d0, base=0x804140, ec=..., bytes_transferred=1) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:651
#9  0x00000000004f0300 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete (this=0x804140, owner=..., ec=..., bytes_transferred=1) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service_operation.hpp:38
#10 0x00000000004f2823 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one (this=0x8084d0, lock=..., this_thread=..., ec=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:372
#11 0x00000000004f23a1 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run (this=0x8084d0, ec=...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:149
#12 0x00000000004f2abc in boost::asio::io_service::run (this=0x7ef540) at /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:59
#13 0x00000000004f7c89 in MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::Listener(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const () at /home/ubuntu/MoltenCore/MoltenCore/src/shared/Network/Listener.hpp:84
#14 0x0000000000505624 in std::_Bind_simple<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::Listener(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)::{lambda()#1} ()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x8049c8)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1531
#15 0x0000000000504f38 in std::_Bind_simple<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::Listener(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)::{lambda()#1} ()>::operator()() (this=0x8049c8) at /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1520
#16 0x0000000000504416 in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<MaNGOS::Listener<AuthSocket>::Listener(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)::{lambda()#1} ()> >::_M_run() (this=0x8049b0) at /usr/include/c++/5/thread:115
#17 0x00007ffff6c98c80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#18 0x00007ffff7bc16ba in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff4ec9700) at pthread_create.c:333
#19 0x00007ffff63fe82d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

EDIT: 
NetworkThread.hpp:

```
template <typename SocketType>
class NetworkThread
{
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service m_service;

        std::mutex m_socketLock;
        std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<SocketType>> m_sockets;

        // note that the work member *must* be declared after the service member for the work constructor to function correctly
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;

        std::thread m_serviceThread;

    public:
        NetworkThread() : m_work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_service))
        {
            m_serviceThread = std::thread([this] { boost::system::error_code ec; this->m_service.run(ec); });
        }

        ~NetworkThread()
        {
            // Allow io_service::run() to exit.
            m_work.reset();
            m_service.stop();
            m_serviceThread.join();

            // attempt to gracefully close any open connections
            for (auto i = m_sockets.begin(); i != m_sockets.end();)
            {
                auto const current = i;
                ++i;

                if (!(*current)->IsClosed())
                    (*current)->Close();
            }
        }

        size_t Size() const { return m_sockets.size(); }

        std::shared_ptr<SocketType> CreateSocket();

        void RemoveSocket(Socket *socket)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_socketLock);
            m_sockets.erase(socket->shared<SocketType>());
        }
};

template <typename SocketType>
std::shared_ptr<SocketType> NetworkThread<SocketType>::CreateSocket()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_socketLock);

    auto const i = m_sockets.emplace(std::make_shared<SocketType>(m_service, [this] (Socket *socket) { this->RemoveSocket(socket); }));

    return *i.first;
}
```

Comment: The use of `const_cast` looks like a red herring. I would guess that you are removing the `constness` of the original object and writing to that. How about stepping through the code or posting a small reproducible example ?

Comment: Just a side note: Why don't you use TrinityCore instead of Mangos ? I believe TrinityCore is more up to date.

Comment: You should accept a `std::shared_ptr` in your `NetworkThread::RemoveSocket` instead of the raw pointer. Also you seem to call at least twice into this function. The lambda of the `std::shared_ptr<SocketType>` and whenever you remove the socket manually. It would be helpful if you could also post the error code with the associated message.

Comment: @Blacktempel  Do you mean that the OP is asking us to find a bug in his app and showing us the third party library code where the bug is the least likely to be?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy For me it's pretty obvious which open-source project this is. Though it seems like he is trying to rewrite existing code, as the project does not yet (at least it seems like from the code) support boost-asio. https://github.com/mangos/MaNGOS

Comment: This code looks similar to the code used in https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/ Not the same, but trying to implement the same functionality.

Comment: oh.. problem is, boost asio is pretty much self-sufficient.

Comment: BTW, These code are from https://github.com/cmangos/mangos-classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is totally different:

In your code:

```
template <typename SocketType>
void Listener<SocketType>::OnAccept(
    NetworkThread<SocketType> *worker, 
    std::shared_ptr<SocketType> const& socket, 
    const boost::system::error_code &ec )
{
   // at this point, socket has 1 reference count, held by the lambda 
   // in BeginAccept, its reference count cannot increase, since it's 
   // constant.  

    // ...     
    BeginAccept(); // this creates a new, distinct  instance of the lambda 
                   // fuinction object in BeginAccept.

    // when we exit, constrol is given back to calling lambda in BeginAccept
    // its destructor happily deletes the socket, since its reference count
    // is still only 1.
}
```

**Bottom line:** OnAccept() needs to receive the socket pointer by value, and it needs to transfer or store this shared pointer somehow.  This is usually done
by passing the shared_ptr to BeginReceive() **BY VALUE**.  BeginReceive() must then take the responsibility to keep the socket pointer alive until the connection dies, this, it usually does that by passing the pointer back to itself, either as a parameter, or as a lambda capture, always by value.

The easiest way to fix your code is to move the call to `StartAsyncRead()` to `OnAccept()`, since there is a convenient copy of a shared_ptr of the socket there.

Comment: I just post the `CreateSocket` implementation code. I the shared_ptr returned by `CreateSocket` is already held in a set. So I don't know if it's still apply the destruction rule you mentioned.

Comment: @ryancheung If you're 100% sure that the pointer of `std::shared_ptr` won't be destructed by anything you can pass it by reference... still you should rather do it by value.

Comment: I looked at the NetworkThreadClass, and only 8 lines of it are actually doing something useful work for async i/o. 4 lines of declaration and 4 lines of code.  It's the first time I see an array of sockets being kept.  I wonder what's its use.  Which code is yours and which is the third party library?

Comment: Thanks @Michaël Roy and @Blacktempel, the problem was fixed by passing the shared ptr of Socket by value. Since we have used `socket->Open();`, the reference count in the shared ptr must increase, or the socket may be destroyed somewhere.